# doctrine 2 error with setHydrator

Tags: php, doctrine-orm, zend-framework2

using zend 2 with standart app structure.
i have Entity:

```
module\University\src\University\Entity\Student.php
<?php
namespace University\Entity;

use Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection;
use Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @ORM\Table(name="students")
 */
class Student
{   //more stuff
}
```

and a form

```
University\src\University\Form\StudentForm.php
<?php
namespace University\Form;

use DoctrineModule\Stdlib\Hydrator\DoctrineObject as DoctrineHydrator;
use Zend\Form\Form;
use Zend\ServiceManager\ServiceManager;

class StudentForm extends Form
{
    parent::__construct('student-form');
    $entityManager = $serviceManager->get('Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager');

    $this->setHydrator(new DoctrineHydrator($entityManager, 'University\Entity\Student')); // this row cause the error

    // more stuff
}
```

In the controller:

```
<?php
namespace University\Controller;

use Zend\Mvc\Controller\AbstractActionController,
    Zend\View\Model\ViewModel,
    University\Entity\Student,
    University\Form\StudentForm;

class StudentController extends AbstractActionController
{
    public function indexAction()
    {

        $form = new StudentForm($this->serviceLocator);
        // more stuffs
    }
}
```

and doctrine throws me error:

```
File:
\vendor\doctrine\common\lib\Doctrine\Common\Persistence\Mapping\MappingException.php:38
Message:
The class 'University\Entity\Student' was not found in the chain configured namespaces \Entity
```

im following [this](https://github.com/doctrine/DoctrineModule/blob/69dacc5d90724a9b579de34327e5a60fe41d6452/docs/hydrator.md#a-complete-example-using-zendform) tutorial.

Any ideas why i got this error and how to fix it?

**EDIT**
I find how to fix the problem and why its caused. The answer is moved into the topic answers.'

Comment: First guess: wrong driver configuration for doctrine. Going by the error my absolute guess is that the `namespace University;` is missing inside the doctrine-config.

Comment: Indeed. @Tudor please paste relevant config (the one of the https://github.com/doctrine/DoctrineORMModule readme)

Comment: Hi guys, thank you for your fast response and sorry for my slow one :>
You were right, i got it working now but with this config in module.config.php (im gonna edit the main post)

Comment: Rather than editing the question, the "done thing" round here is to *answer* your own question, and then accept that answer. See http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/17463/can-i-answer-my-own-questions-even-those-where-i-knew-the-answer-before-asking

Comment: 10x IMSoP, from now on i will no longer make this mistake.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution. The problem was in my module.config.php, i was using the following doctrine settings:

```
'doctrine' => array(
    'driver' => array(
        __NAMESPACE__ . '_driver' => array(
            'class' => 'Doctrine\ORM\Mapping\Driver\AnnotationDriver',
            'cache' => 'array',
            'paths' => array(__DIR__ . '/../src/' . __NAMESPACE__ . '/Entity')
        ),
        'orm_default' => array(
            'drivers' => array(
                __NAMESPACE__ . '\Entity' => __NAMESPACE__ . '_driver'
            )
        )
    )
)
```

not pretty sure how to edit the code above to get it working, 
but this is how i made it to work:

```
// Doctrine config
'doctrine' => array(
    'driver' => array(
        // defines an annotation driver with two paths, and names it `my_annotation_driver`
        'my_annotation_driver' => array(
            'class' => 'Doctrine\ORM\Mapping\Driver\AnnotationDriver',
            'cache' => 'array',
            'paths' => array(
                __DIR__ . '/../src/University/Entity',
                'another/path'
            ),
        ),

        // default metadata driver, aggregates all other drivers into a single one.
        // Override `orm_default` only if you know what you're doing
        'orm_default' => array(
            'drivers' => array(
                // register `my_annotation_driver` for any entity under namespace `My\Namespace`
                'University\Entity' => 'my_annotation_driver'
            )
        )
    )
)
```

10x u guys for the help!

**EDIT:**
I find out why the 1st configuration (with the **NAMESPACES**) didnt work, its because there wasnt set any namespace on the top of module.config.php file, so if u want to configure with the **NAMESPACE** annotation, just add 'namespace YourModuleName;'